# Bi-directional One-to-One mapping with @EmbeddedId and Foreign key

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one, bidirectional

I'm having some trouble with a bi-directional one-to-one mapping, using @EmbeddedId and Foreign key.

Every time a perform a `em.find(Bkftd03,Bkftd03PK.class)` y obtain the same error:

```
Error performing load command : org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: 
Provided id of the wrong type for class com.ibc.gsr.entity.Bkftd03. Expected: class com.ibc.gsr.entity.Bkftd03PK, got class com.ibc.gsr.entity.Bkftd27PK
```

The main table structure looks something like this:

```
Entity
@Table(name="BKFTD03")
@NamedQuery(name="Bkftd03.findAll", query="SELECT b FROM Bkftd03 b")
public class Bkftd03 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private Bkftd03PK id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="PRO_NUM_PROPUESTA", referencedColumnName="PRW_NUM_PROPUESTA", nullable=false)
    })
    private Bkftd27 bkftd27;
```

And the inverse mapping table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BKFTD27")
@NamedQuery(name="Bkftd27.findAll", query="SELECT b FROM Bkftd27 b")
public class Bkftd27 implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Bkftd27PK id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="bkftd27")
    private Bkftd03 bkftd03;
```

And the PK for both entities:

```
@Embeddable
public class Bkftd03PK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="PRO_NUM_PROPUESTA", nullable=false, precision=12, columnDefinition="NUMBER(12,0)")
    private long proNumPropuesta;

 .....

@Embeddable
public class Bkftd27PK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="PRW_NUM_PROPUESTA",nullable=false, precision=12, columnDefinition="NUMBER(12,0)")
    private long prwNumPropuesta;

 .......
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the entire code for the fetch.

Comment: The problem is not in the fetch code, the problem is that Hibernate try to cast both PK (Bkftd27PK / Bkftd03PK). The fetch code is em.find(Bkftd03,Bkftd03PK.class)

Comment: have you discovered what's wrong with your code?